# Custom Window Maximise CentOS 7 XFCE

Tags: linux, centos, xfce, gui

I wanted to know if it's possible to set a custom limit for how far windows maximise in CentOS using XFCE4. My second panel is slightly elevated from the bottom of the screen and I wanted to know if it's possible to prevent windows from maximising beyond the second panel.

Currently, I have it set to `Intelligently` hide the panel when a window is maximised which is working okay at the moment, but Ideally, I'd like to keep the second panel always displayed.

Thank you in advance.

[image: XFCE4 Panel 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem after some further research.

Turns out under `Settings Manager > Workspaces > Margins` you can set an area where windows will not be placed.

This solution is working well for my needs and I hope this may provide a solution to anyone else in the future.

[image: XFCE4 Workspace Margin Settings]